# SQL Split string between two values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some values in my db

```
id  |  string
    |
1   |  AB.1234.cd
2   |  EF.5678.gh
ecc..
```

my goal is split the string value between 2 points.
At the end "AB.1234.cd" must be "1234"

Thanks in advance

Comment: See substring_index

Comment: The numbers always going to be in the middle of periods (".")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, *twice*:

```sql
SELECT id, string, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, '.', -2), '.', 1) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

If your string always has that format, the simplest method is `substr()`:

```
substr(string, 4, 4)
```

If you want the second value between periods, you can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select x.*, regexp_substr(string, '[^.]+', 1, 2), substr(string, 4, 4)
from (select 1 as id, 'AB.1234.cd' as string union all
      select 2 as id, 'EF.5678.gh'
     ) x
```